# Как настроить nginx для отображения двух сайтов?

Tags: nginx

Есть два сайта - site1 и site2, которые лежат в директориях **/var/www/site1** и **/var/www/site2** соответственно.
Необходимо, что бы по запросу http://localhost/ открывался site1, а при запросе http://localhost/site2 открывался site2.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/site1**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    set         $base /var/www/site1;
    root        $base/;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/site2**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name localhost/site2;
    set         $base /var/www/site2;
    root        $base/;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

На данный момент открывается только site1, а при обращении к http://localhost/site2 выдаёт:

> 404 Not Found
> nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Как настроить nginx так, что бы по запросу http://localhost/ открывался site1, а при запросе http://localhost/site2 открывался site2?

Comment: Если адрес сайта один `localhost`, то и секция `server` тоже должна быть ровно одна, а уже внутри неё сделать два `location /` и `location /site2`

Comment: Добавил второй location /site2 в секции server, результат тот же >404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Значит читайте в error.log, кого и почему nginx не смог найти

Comment: на ютубе посмотри, там есть несколько видео. Как раз по твоей теме

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. к обоим сайтам вы хотите обращаться по имени хоста **localhost**, то файл **/etc/nginx/sites-available/site2** вам вообще не нужен.

Измените файл **/etc/nginx/sites-available/site1**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    root        /var/www;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ ^/(?!site2) {
        rewrite (.*) /site1$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Не работает, при обращении к localhost ошибка 500, при обращении localhost/site2 ошибка 404

Comment: что в логе ошибок ?

Answer (score 0):

Это для Django, но думаю тоже подойдет.

```
location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn_site1.sock;
    }


location /site2 {
            proxy_set_header SCRIPT_NAME /site2;
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn_site2.sock;
    }
```